# Matching in SICStus prolog

Tags: prolog, theorem-proving

This is my code, which is for Satchmo theorem proving. It does some unification.

```
:- op(700, xfx, ==>).
:- op(400, yfx, &).
:- op(400, yfx, or).

fact([a, 9]).
fact([b, 9]).
rule([a, X] & [b, X] ==> [c, X]). %% horn bit
rule([c, X] ==> [r, X] or [s, X]). %% non horn bit
rule([r, X] ==> [t, X]).
rule([s, X] ==> [t, X]).

horn(A & B) :- 
    !,
    horn(A),
    horn(B).
horn(A or B) :-  
    !,
    (horn(A); horn(B)).
horn(P) :-
    fact(P).
horn(P) :-
    temp(P). 
horn(P) :-
    rule(SUBGOALS ==> P),
    \+ P = (_A or _B),
    horn(SUBGOALS).

satchmo(P) :-
    retractall(temp(_)),
    prove(P).

prove(P) :-
    horn(P).
prove(P) :-
    rule(LHS ==> (A or B)),
    horn(LHS),
    \+ horn(A or B),

cprove(A ==> P), 
    cprove(B ==> P). 

cprove(A ==> P) :-
    try(A),
    (prove(P) ->
    untry(A);
    (untry(A), fail)).

try(A & B) :-
    !,
    try(A),
    try(B).
try(A) :-
    assert(temp(A)).

untry(A & B) :-
    !,
    untry(A),
    untry(B).
untry(A) :-
    retract(temp(A)).
```

To understand how is it working, we can do that by ?- spy([satchmo]).

1- if the given query is fact as:

```
?- satchmo([a, 9]). 
yes.
```

or

```
?- satchmo([b, 9]).
yes.
```

the program will prove it as it is a fact.

2- If the query in the horn bit as:

```
?- satchmo([c, 9]). 
yes.
```

the program will prove it as it is the horn rule.

3- If the query in the non-horn bit as:

```
?- satchmo([t, 9]). 
yes.
```

It'll be proved as well.

This is working perfectly. But when I have tried to change it a bit. Instead of unification I need to do another kind of matching which can prove the following:

if I have:

```
rule[living, X] ==> [mortal, X]. 
[man, socrates].
```

I would like to prove:

```
?- satchmo([mortal, socrates]). 
yes.
```

To do this I have amend my code a bit, so instead of having:

```
horn(P):-
    fact(P).
```

I put something very similar:

```
horn(P):-
    match(P, P0),
    fact(P0).
```

and I have defined match as:

```
match(X, Y):-
    X=Y.
```

I know that I have not do anything by this move, but I am thinking to amend the definition of match a bit to be able to prove what I need.

I am stuck somewhere here, look at my current code.

```
:- op(700, xfx, ==>).
:- op(400, yfx, &).
:- op(400, yfx, or).
:- op(400, yfx, <<<).

fact([a, 9]).
fact([b, 9]).
rule([a, X] & [b, X] ==> [c, X]). %% horn bit
rule([c, X] ==> [r, X] or [s, X]). %% non horn bit
rule([r, X] ==> [t, X]).
rule([s, X] ==> [t, X]).

man <<< human.
human <<< animal.
animal <<< living.

subset(X, X).
subset(X, Y) :-
    X <<< Y.
subset(X, Z) :-
    X <<< Y,
    subset(Y, Z).

horn(A & B) :- 
    !,
    horn(A),
    horn(B).
horn(A or B) :-  
    !,
    (horn(A); horn(B)).
horn(P) :-
    fact(P).
horn(P) :-
    temp(P). 
horn(P) :-
    rule(SUBGOALS ==> P),
    \+ P = (_A or _B),
    horn(SUBGOALS).

satchmo(P) :-
    retractall(temp(_)),
    prove(P).

prove(P) :-
    horn(P).
prove(P) :-
    rule(LHS ==> (A or B)),
    horn(LHS),
    \+ horn(A or B),
    cprove(A ==> P), 
    cprove(B ==> P). 

cprove(A ==> P) :-
    try(A),
    (prove(P) ->
    untry(A);
    (untry(A), fail)).

try(A & B) :-
    !,
    try(A),
    try(B).
try(A) :-
    assert(temp(A)).

untry(A & B) :-
    !,
    untry(A),
    untry(B).
untry(A) :-
    retract(temp(A)).
```

Here, we can test the subset:

```
?- subset(human, man). 
yes.
```

The problem here, is I do not know how to achieve my goal by proving:

```
?- satchmo([mortal, socrates]).
yes.
```

from:

```
[living, X] ==> [mortal, X]. 
[man, socrates].
```

Could it be done by changing the definition of match? If not, is there any other method to do it?

Comment: Have you tried using `trace` to examine the path of your logic?

Comment: yes I have trace it by writing ?- spy([satchmo]). and tried to prove the fact, the horn rule, and the non-horn rule.

Comment: You are wanting to prove, `satchmo([mortal, socrates])`, but a "trace by inspection" shows that, ultimately, the rules lead back to the facts `fact/1` and `rule/1`, which all have an atom in the first element of their two-element lists none of which match `mortal`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, done,

The solution of this problem is simply by changing the definition of match, so it will be as follows:

```
match(P, P0) :-
    P = [X, _],
    P0 = [Y, _],
    subset(Y, X).

subset(X, X).

subset(X, Y) :-
    X <<< Y.

subset(X, Z) :-
    X <<< Y,
    subset(Y, Z).
```

and when I have this facts:

```
fact([man, socrates]).
man <<< human.
human <<< animal.
animal <<< living.
```

and this rule:

```
rule([living, X] ==> [mortal, X]).
```

I can prove:

```
?- satchmo([mortal, socrates]).
```